# jQuery click events overriding each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
$('.io-sidebar-section').click(function () {
      console.log('Section Clicked');
      $(this).next().fadeToggle('fast',function(){});
    });

    $('.io-sidebar-section-advanced-toggle').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().next().children('.io-sidebar-link-advanced').fadeToggle('fast',function(){});
    });
```

the advanced toggle is inside of a sidebar section. When I click on the advanced toggle, it executes the sidebar section click.

How can I seperate these two out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method of the event object inside the `click` event handler for the child element:

```
$('.io-sidebar-section-advanced-toggle').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().next().children('.io-sidebar-link-advanced').fadeToggle('fast',function(){});
});
```

From the jQuery docs, here's what `stopPropagation` does:

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

As mentioned in the comments, if you prefer you can alternatively use `return false` in the event handler (in this particular case, as far as I can tell anyway - it will also cause `preventDefault` which may not be what you want to happen). My personal preference is to use `stopPropagation` but it's completely up to you.

Comment: It's even easier to just `return(false)` from the click handler and jQuery will handle the stop propagation for you.

Comment: Just a note, returning `false` will also prevent the default event from firing (akin to calling `e.preventDefault();`). This might not be desirable.

Comment: @Clive - Also true, I just added that to the answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid events bubbling up by using jQuery's bind function and preventBubble argument.

http://api.jquery.com/bind/